# JAXB unmarshal list element by element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I need some help with unmarshalling some XML. Especially with unmarshalling a list of elements. See the following example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="element")
public class Element
{
    private ArrayList<Element> children;

    public ArrayList<Element> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "children")
    @XmlElement(name = "element")
    public void setChildren(ArrayList<Element> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

This will unmarshal the list perfectly, BUT what I need is an **unmarshalling** of all children **element by element** and adding them through some "addElement" method:

```
    public void addElement(Element element) {
        children.add(element)
    }
```

Is this possible with some simple annotation *magic*? Of course I could loop through the elements and call "addElement".

Comment: Let me guess, you have a huge XML and don't want to unmarshall all of it, but rather "stream" it to some recipient? Look in the direction of StAX (you can use it with JAXB very well).

Comment: nice guess, but no :P There is no crazy use case behind this. Simply wondered if this is possible and I couldn't find anything on the web.

Comment: A pity. This is a good use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pretend your appender is a setter.

[Example](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/blob/master/runtime/src/test/java/org/hisrc/xml/bind/tests/addelement/AddElementTest.java):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "element")
public class Element {
    private List<Element> children = new LinkedList<Element>();

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Element> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "element")
    public void setChild(Element child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    private String value;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

JAXB will invoke the setter every time the `element` element is encountered. This adds the unmarshalled element to the list. The list getter is `@XmlTransient` to avoid handling by JAXB.

**Update**

I've forgotten to add that this won't work with the `@XmlWrapperElement` as it expects a collection property.